# Why am I not receiving the last line? (Python Serial Communication)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I have a script that sends a command to a peripheral machine and then reads what the machine sends out. For any "registered" command, the peripheral will send a "RCD" message first, stuff in the middle, and then a "EOM" message last. I can receive everything except the last line.

My connection is set up with:

```
ser=serial.Serial(
    port = portin,           #User inputs selection from available ports
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)
```

I send my message using `ser.write(send_cmd)`, and read information using the `readline()` function. Specifically:

```
While (True):
  recd_line = ser.readline()
  sys.stdout.write(recd_line.decode('utf-8'))         # prints stuff for user to see on terminal live
  if not recd_line:                                   # if not receiving info, break out of reading loop
    break
```

I've verified (through manually sending out the command on Termie) that the peripheral sends out (exactly):

```
RCD<NUL><LF>
....<NUL><LF>
stuff<NUL><LF>
....<NUL><LF>
EOM<NUL><NUL>
```

but my program only receives(exactly):

```
RCD \n\r
....\n\r
stuff\n\r
....
```

I've also tried setting a manual timeout that compares start time to current time using `time.time()` as my break condition, and I still don't receive that last message; I just receive blank lines. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: What is this `EOM` message that is received last? Can you specify the exact binary values that the peripheral sends?

Comment: @quamrana the literal EOM message that is received last is `***TSD***`. It's received from the peripheral and [every line] is decoded using `decoded_msg = recd_msg.decode('utf-8')`. The binary representation of this is: `00101010 00101010 00101010 01010100 01010011 01000100 00101010 00101010 00101010`.

Comment: Yes, just as I thought. The last line has no `\n` terminator, unlike all the other lines, so `ser.readline()` will hang (or return an empty string on timeout). The documentation says you have to be careful with `readline()`.

Comment: @quamrana Thank you for this suggestion! However, I just tried to use `ser.read()` instead of readline() and I'm still encountering the same issue... Could there be another thing I'm missing?

Comment: `ser.read()` should 'work' just fine if all you are doing is printing the data to `stdout`. (although you may need to add `sys.stdout.write("\n")` just before the `break`)

Comment: @quamrana I'm still not able to see the final line... I double checked on Termie what I'm receiving (restating here that on Termie I can actually see the final line), and I noticed that after each line received, I get a `<NUL>` and a `<LF>`. A notable difference in the final two lines indicates that I am receiving this as the second to last line: `stuff stuff <NUL><LF><LF>` `***TSD***<LF><LF>`. Specifically, in the second to last and last lines I'm getting ***two*** `<LF>` instead of 1. I dont think I'm receiving the last <NUL> or <LF>s from the second to last line...

Comment: Ok, so how are you creating the `ser` variable? Can you update your question with your `ser = Serial(...)` line?

Comment: (Also the second last line with `<LF><LF>` may make `readline()` produce your second last line, plus a blank line which then causes `if not recd_line:` to fire and quit the loop)

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for your help thus far. I updated the question to include the `ser` configuration and include information about `<NUL><LF>`. In regards to your last comment, I've swapped over to using `read()` instead of `readline()` for now so I don't get caught with any `\n` characters.

Comment: Please double check your question for the details about `<NUL><LF>` etc. Your comment above indicates that you see `<LF><LF>`.

Comment: @quamrana Thank you for catching my mistake, my deepest apologies for my initial typo (it seems my dyslexia is catching up to me). I can confirm the last line received is `***TSD***<NUL><NUL>`

Answer (score 0):

I would just read in all the available characters into one big string until the timeout forces `ser.read()` to timeout and return an empty string.

Then you can reconstruct your lines by using `.split()` in some form.

```py
rcv_lines = ''
while True:
    stuff = ser.read(size=10).decode('utf-8')
    rcv_lines += stuff
    if not stuff:
        break
rcv_lines = rcv_lines.split('\0\n')
print(rcv_lines)
```

I did some experiments using this as an input string:

```py
'''\
RCD\0
...\0
stuff\0
....\0
EOM\0\0'''
```

The output from the above code was:

```
['RCD', '...', 'stuff', '....', 'EOM\x00\x00']
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  Unfortunately, this seems to yield the same results; i.e., the last thing I receive (I'm splitting at \n\r) is `'stuff\x00'`. If splitting at \x00, I receive `'stuff',''`. For some reason it's still missing the entirety of the last line. When available, I'll try to debug further with a scope and see if there's something being transmitted that I'm missing.